# Reliable counter of midnight occurrences

Tags: objective-c, date, timezone, counter

I have a certain amount of elements, and each of these elements represents one day. **Each time midnight occurs (i.e. >>>*user*<<< time = 00:00), I want the "current" element in the list to expire (and the next one will take its place).** Now this seems easy and all, but when you start scratching the surface it's a mess (at least according to me). The problems begin with time zones. If midnight occurs, and after this I change my time zone to one where this particular midnight has not occured yet, then when it does occur "again" in the new time zone, I do not want to count it again (the expired element should remain expired while the element that took its place should count as the current one). Also, when the app is suspended/shut down for a couple of days, I want it to update itself based on the number of valid midnights that occured since last use (as I see it, this makes using UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification pointless, as it is only sent for the most recent passed midnight).

Ideally, I would like these elements to be totally unaware of dates and time; they should simply be a list 0,1,2,3,... together with a "current element" pointer (i.e. a simple integer), which will be increased for each valid midnight occurence.

How would you suggest that I should implement this?

Comment: Don't forget that in some time zones, daylight saving time transitions will create a gap where midnight does not exist.  For example, in 2014 for Brazil, the clock jumps from 11:59:59 on Oct 18 to 01:00:00 on October 19, skipping the midnight hour completely.  The approach in Gavin's comments (the one I up-voted)  is sound, but looking at "midnight" is not.

Comment: @MattJohnson Very good point (didn't think about that), thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base it on UTC midnight, so that no matter what time zone you're in, you're unaffected by the local time change. It eliminates the time zone issue altogether.

Comment: Sounds beautifully simple, but will this mean that users being in a time zone with a nonzero offset from UTC will see their current element expire at THEIR midnight?

Comment: @LukasKalinski This would mean that no matter what time zone somebody was in, so no matter where they were in the world, it would expire at the same time, which would only be midnight in one part of the world. So if somebody lived in US Central time zone, it would expire at 6pm local time. But if you want to have consistency when moving between time zones, then having it be fixed to UTC is one of the only reasonable options. An alternative would be to base it on a US time zone, such as US Central time zone, if your app will mainly only be used in the US/Canada.

Comment: Well, then unfortunately this is not a solution to my problem. The whole point is that the expiration occurs on the *user's* midnight, otherwise the app would become more or less useless. As I target "anyone", restricting myself to one time zone is not an option either (especially as people in one specific time zone still can travel).

Comment: @LukasKalinski Well then it sounds like you have to decide how you want to handle the case that the user switches time zones. This seems like more of a business decision, what experience you want for the user when they switch time zones, than a technical problem.

Comment: I did specify the business decision in my question (i.e. expiration of an element should be irreversible), so obviously that was not my question. My question was whether there is some API class or some other solution/"pattern" that could help in accomplishing this behaviour. I know UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification would have been a perfect solution, IF it could be guaranteed that it is sent for *every* passed midnight and not only the last one.

Comment: @LukasKalinski Just keep track of what day you were last on, and update it with the new day when it changes. You don't need the notification to tell you that it's a new day, you can just check which day it is upon bringing the app into the foreground, and compare that to what day it was the last time the app was in the foreground.

Comment: Yes, but notifications would have spared me the headaches of thinking about time zones. What you suggest is very easy in one time zone, but it seems to be much more problematic when multiple time zones have to be taken into account. The risk of bugs increases in a very important part of the application and identifying the necessary test cases is not a straight forward task to do. But I guess from your last comment that avoiding time zones altogether is not realistic?

Comment: @LukasKalinski You don't necessarily have to think about the time zones specifically. Just get the user's local time and look at what the date is. If that date ever goes back (like they move to an earlier time zone and it happens to make it a day earlier) then handle that in your app logic appropriately. If you don't ever want your "expiration" or whatever to go back to an earlier one, then treat going back a day as still being on the later day. So, if it is Feb 25th, but they move back a time zone and it's Feb 24th, treat it as that they're still on Feb 25th.

Comment: Now that sounds like an interesting way to see it, thanks! I will try to elaborate on this now and you'll get your tick on success (not necessarily today though).